# Requests Python: Passing payload POST request

Tags: python, http, request

I'm automatizing the configuration of network devices. I have to login each device, change network address and passwords. 
Using: [Requests Python Module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

The first process I need to do, is login. It's a simple form. By inspecting the website I will analyze the Headers and the parameters necessary:

```
General:
Request URL:http://192.168.7.2:8000/api/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.7.2:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Request Headers:
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.7.2:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://192.168.7.2:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://192.168.7.2:8000/login.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

Request Payload:
{"user":"user","password":"password"}
```

Following the documentation I got in this code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://192.168.7.2:8000/api/login"
payload = {"user":"admin","password":"admin"}
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
#r.encoding = "UTF-8"
print r.text
```

What does happen? Well, running the script I receive this output: `{"errno":"20"}` the same error if I login with user/password wrong. That's is not possible, because using this user/password through of web interface, the authentication is successful. I think that something is wrong in the code.

Changing the payload format: Same error `{"errno":"20"}`

```
payload = (("user","admin"),("password","admin"))
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
#r.encoding = "UTF-8"
print r.text
```

**JSON-Enconded**: Reports a different error: `{"errno":"0","key":"fc2d253fb9b25d5880dd4843f439bc7b"}`

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://192.168.7.2:8000/api/login"
payload = {"user":"admin","password":"admin"}
r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload))
#r.encoding = "UTF-8"
print r.text
```

**Passing json directly**: Reports `{"errno":"0","key":"6f7ed0ae5f14833f689fcb34c2bf5b77"}`

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://192.168.7.2:8000/api/login"
payload = {"user":"admin","password":"admin"}
r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
#r.encoding = "UTF-8"
print r.text
```

Using a different url:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://192.168.7.2:8000/login.html"
payload = {"user":"admin","password":"admin"}
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)
#r.encoding = "UTF-8"
print r.text
```

It's reports `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3426-3427: ordinal not in range(128)`

Printing `r.encoding` -> `ISO-8859-1` is the output.

Set `r.encoding="utf-8"` and `print r.text` Output: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 3426: ordinal not in range(128)`

Anyone has experience with this lib?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the username and password in the headers.

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://192.168.7.2:8000/api/login"
headers = {"user":"admin","password":"admin"}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print r.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Still returning ``{"errno":"20'"}``. Do you think that the problem can be the device firmware?

Comment: where is payload?